# Why do names that are not part of the implementation still use the double underscore naming convention?

Tags: c

Aren't double underscores reserved for the implementation? I'm referring to something like [this](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Limera1n_Exploit). People seem to ignore this convention all the time.

Here's the code:

```
signed int __cdecl upload_exploit() {
int device_type;
signed int payload_address;
int free_address;
int deviceerror;
char *chunk_headers_ptr;
...
```

[Here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Reserved-Names.html) is where the convention is defined:

> In addition to the names documented in this manual, reserved names
> include all external identifiers (global functions and variables) that
> begin with an underscore (‘_’) and all identifiers regardless of use
> that begin with either two underscores or an underscore followed by a
> capital letter are reserved names. This is so that the library and
> header files can define functions, variables, and macros for internal
> purposes without risk of conflict with names in user programs.

Edit:

**Although this was a bad example, the spirit of my question still stands: I have seen programmers "incorrectly" use the double underscore. What connotation does it carry? What are they trying to convey about the function/keyword?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People write a lot of things that are invalid C. Lack of strictness by compilers is the principal reason they're able to get away with it. But in the case of the example you linked, it does not seem like the code is doing anything wrong. Rather than illegally defining identifiers in the reserved namespace, it's using implementation-defined identifiers provided by the implementation in the standard headers.

Comment: " Lack of strictness by compilers" -- The C standard is explicit about what things C compilers are required to produce diagnostics for ... and use of reserved identifiers is certainly not one of them.

Comment: Thank you for the level-headed response. I normally use Linux, so I made the faulty assumption that the keyword was created by a user.

Comment: @occamsrazor So assuming that there is only one implementation in the world is "level-headed"? Before assuming a name reserved to the implementation in some program is not reserved to the implementation under which that program is intended to run, it would be wise to check that assumption.

Comment: @JimBalter: I'm aware that compilers are not required to produce diagnostics for everything that's invalid C, but (1) GCC at least fails to produce diagnostics (by default) for some things it's required to, which are blatantly invalid C, and (2) allowing invalid C, even if it's not required that the compiler diagnose it, seriously hurts C's reputation by allowing so much junk code to persist.

Comment: a) gcc has flags that make it produce diagnostics for everything it is required to. gcc is a program that provides many implementations, some of which are strictly conforming to the C standard and some are not. It's not gcc's fault if a user picks the wrong one. b) That's the least thing that hurts C's "reputation". It is 2015. I was on the C standards committee and wrote C for decades; I've wised up.

Comment: I suppose we can just agree to disagree.

Comment: So you disagree that gcc has flags that make it produce diagnostics for everything it is required to? As to whether the fact that C compilers don't do things that the C standard was expressly intended by its authors not to require them to do "hurts C's reputation", I didn't disagree, if you would read what I wrote carefully.

Comment: I think we disagree on the importance of rejecting invalid (and often dangerously so; at least non-portable) code by default and on the extent to which this makes C look bad. My view is that the indirect effects are serious: when the compiler doesn't reject the wrong code, it persists and multiplies by cargo cult effects, and you have perceptions that C code is not portable, that compilers are always breaking things, that C is a language where you program to "what happens to work" rather than to a well-specified language, etc.

Answer (score 1):

`__cdecl` is a Microsoft specific function qualifier.  It is indeed part of the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

As a famous science fiction writer once said, "90% of everything is crap", and sadly, that applies to computer programs (and computer programmers), too.

It's true that most identifiers starting with underscore are reserved, but it's also true that (a) this rule is very rarely enforced, and consequently (b) it's very widely ignored.  It bugs me, too.

In answer to your followup question, those programmers aren't even sure exactly what they're trying to convey.  A "special" identifier, a "different" identifier, a "meta" identifier.  They've seen the underscore used like that, so they think it must be a good idea to mimic it.

Please don't mimic them, but don't worry if you can't understand what they were trying to accomplish, because I usually don't, either.